# How do I override styles using dollar sign ($) in MUI 5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

The code below is from MUI 5, with a MUI 4 solution for change input field when hovering. But it obviously doesn't work, wonder how to achieve this in MUI 5, can't
seem to change the color from the `TextField` upon hovering. This is done using `createTheme` in MUI 5

```js
components: {
  MuiInputLabel: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        color: arcBlue,
        fontSize: '1rem',
      },
    },
  },
  MuiInput: {
    styleOverrides: {
      underline: {
        '&:before': {
          borderBottom: `2px solid ${arcBlue}`,
        },
        // Code from material ui 4
        '&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error):before': {
          borderBottom: `2px solid ${arcGrey}`,
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 4):

The `$` syntax is a feature from JSS, in **MUI v5**, they switch to emotion so it doesn't work anymore, you have 2 options now:

#### Use plain string

From [this](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-styles-with-class-names) section, you can see a list of class names that describe different MUI component states:

| State | Global class name |
| --- | --- |
| active | `.Mui-active` |
| checked | `.Mui-checked` |
| completed | `.Mui-completed` |
| disabled | `.Mui-disabled` |
| error | `.Mui-error` |
| expanded | `.Mui-expanded` |
| focus visible | `.Mui-focusVisible` |
| focused | `.Mui-focused` |
| required | `.Mui-required` |
| selected | `.Mui-selected` |

```
'&&:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):not(.Mui-error):before': {
  borderBottom: `5px solid purple`
}
```

#### Use constant

Most MUI components have their own class constants if you don't want to hardcode the class name:

```
import { [component]Classes } from "@mui/material/[Component]";
import { inputClasses } from "@mui/material/Input";
```

```
[`&&:hover:not(${inputClasses.disabled}):not(${inputClasses.focused}):before`]: {
  borderBottom: `5px solid purple`
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Reference

- https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-themes-styleoverrides-to-emotion

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it. It worked

Comment: @DiegoFranco, also note that you need to double the ampersand `&&` to increase the CSS specificity in your specific case, otherwise it is overridden by MUI styles.

Comment: thanks man. Appreciate it.